# scrollTop não funciona

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma div `topoMaior` e quero que quando a pessoa der scroll de uns 50px, ela fique com `top:0`.

Fiz isso com Jquery:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
    $(".topoMaior").css("top","0");
}
```

E não rolou.

Comment: Essa div tem posição absoluta ou fixa?

Comment: A div tem posição `fixed`

Comment: Tem um event handler para isso? como está essa função?

Comment: Teste isto e diga o que a consola mostra: http://jsfiddle.net/kj53q3kb/

Comment: @Sergio funcionou! :D e como eu faria um animate disso?

Comment: @FelipeStoker o que é que queres animar? onde está o `".topoMaior"` na página antes de aplicares `top: 0` ? se colocares o HTML posso dar uma resposta com um exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que falta nessa ideia o [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) que é ativado quando um `scroll` acontece.

Pode fazer isso assim:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // correr código
});
```

Para juntar uma animação pode fazer assim:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".topoMaior").stop().animate({top: 0});
        $(".topoMaior").css("background", "#ccf");
    } else {
        $(".topoMaior").stop().animate({top: 200});
        $(".topoMaior").css("background", "#669");
    };
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w84mb94q/

---

Se quiser pode fazer isso com CSS, que é a maneira mais correta, usando JS somente para aplicar uma classe. Exemplo:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) $(".topoMaior").addClass('scroll');
    else $(".topoMaior").removeClass('scroll');
});
```

```css
.topoMaior {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #669;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.main {
    height: 2000px;
}
.scroll {
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topoMaior"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```