# Fazer animate com scrollTop

Tags: jquery

Quero que a div `#parte3` fiquei `display:block` quando chegar no **scrollTop = 1110**.
Minha sintaxe

```
console.log($(window).scrollTop(), $(window).scrollTop() > 1110);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1110) {
        $("#parte3").animate("display", "block");
    };
```

Comment: Não consigo imaginar qual seria o sentido de animar a propriedade `display`, visto que não tem situações intermediárias. Mais fácil você explicar o resultado desejado do que o jeito que está tentando fazer. Não seria simplesmente `.css( "display", "block" )` ? E fora isso, teria que colocar esse teste ao fazer o scroll, e devolver a propriedade para a original se for menor que 1110.

Comment: se possivel poste o resto do código html/css  ou algum exemplo na internet.

Comment: Acho que deves usar `.css()` em vez de animate: `$("#parte3").css("display", "block");`. Se quiseres fazer uma transição tens de usar `visibility` ou `$("#parte3").fadeIn()`

Comment: @Sergio eu gostaria de deixar um dalay até a div aparecer, não quero que seja um movimento rápido.

Comment: Já experimentaste com `$("#parte3").fadeIn()` ou `.faeOut()`?

Comment: Qual é a diferença para [esta outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44476/scrolltop-n%C3%A3o-funciona) que você fez em dezembro? O problema parece o mesmo, falta um listener para o evento de scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente é algo nesta linha que você precisa:

```
$(/* elemento desejado, ou simplesmente window */).bind('scroll', function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1110) {
      $("#parte3").css("display", "block");
   } else {                                  // use o else se quiser reverter ao subir.
      $("#parte3").css("display", "none");   // aqui ponha o display original.
   }
});
```

Se está falando de `display:none`, troque por `opacity` com `animate` (ou fadeTo, que é o jeito simples do jQuery).
<sub>EDIT: Como [bem lembrado pelo @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46532/#comment93495_46532), se for pra mostrar 100%, basta usar `.fadeIn()`.</sub>

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1110) {
      $( "#parte3" ).fadeTo( 500, .5 ); // velocidade, transparência
   } ...
```

Neste caso, não use `display:none` inicialmente, e sim `opacity: 0`.

E ainda, se desejar um temporizador antes do efeito, tem o `.delay()`:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1110) {
      $( "#parte3" ).delay( 500 ).fadeIn( 500 );
   } ...
```

Comment: excelente resposta, estou procurando algo desse gênero, tem como? http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index.html

Comment: @FelipeStoker eu acho que até ja vi alguem pedindo este mesmo efeito aqui, vou ver se acho o que era.

Comment: Não era bem isso que eu gostaria, e sim algo parecido com o plugin que postei em minha pergunta, gostaria que as `<section>` fossem aparecendo com o scroll do mouse.